# How to parse part of json data into table

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, url

How to parse following json which I want to parse only few part.

````
```
{
      "head": {
        "StatusValue": 200,
        "StatusText": "Success"
      },
      "body": {
        "Data": [
          {
            "payer_type_id": 1,
            "payer_type": "Self Pay"
          },
          {
            "payer_type_id": 2,
            "payer_type": "Corporate"
          },
          {
            "payer_type_id": 6,
            "payer_type": "Insurance"
          }
        ],
        "RecordCount": 3,
        "TotalRecords": null
      }
}
````

How to parse only data inside `Data` key.

Expected result should be in following format

```
Date = [["payer_type_id": 1,"payer_type": "Self Pay"],["payer_type_id": 2,"payer_type": "Corporate"],["payer_type_id": 6,"payer_type": "Insurance"]]
```

Comment: check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195555/9136962. Make your own model and parse

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codable protocol for your parsing .

Create Your Model

```
struct APIRootModel : Codable  {
     let head : HeaderModel
     let body : BodyModel
 }

  struct HeaderModel :Codable{
     let StatusValue : Int
     let StatusText : String
  }

 struct BodyModel : Codable{
     let Data : [DataModel]
  }


 struct DataModel : Codable{
     let payer_type_id : Int
     let payer_type : String
 }
```

Decode your json using `JSONDecoder()`

```
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let rootModel = try decoder.decode(APIRootModel.self, from: jsonData)
        print(rootModel.body.data)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Use `[DataModel]` for your tableview datasource.

Comment: Please don't suggest `error.localizedDescription` in a Decoding catch block. You'll get a generic meaningless message. Always `print(error)` to get the real comprehensive error.

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING,CAN YOU SHOW FULL IMPLEMENTATION??

Comment: @Vasucd i am not able to put this data into tableview.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
    let jsonString = "your json string here"
    let dictObject = getDictionaryFromJsonString(dictString: jsonString)
    let bodyDict = dictObject["body"]
    let dataArray = bodyDict["Data"]

   func getDictionaryFromJsonString(dictString:String)-> 
        [String: Any] {
         do {
            return try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
            dictString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, 
            allowLossyConversion: true)!, options:  
            JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! 
            Dictionary
         } catch {
            return [:]
         }
    }
```

Comment: First you need to put your whole json into dictionary object.

Comment: Why `allowLossyConversion`? UTF8 is fully lossless. Why `allowFragments`? For an expected collection type this option is pointless.